# Chain style expression error on swift generator

Tags: swift, generator

swift repl:

```
zip([1,2,3],[7,8,9]).generate().next() 
repl.swift:1:22: error: value of type 'Zip2Generator<IndexingGenerator<Array<Int>>, IndexingGenerator<Array<Int>>>' has no member 'next'
```

but this works:

```
var gen = zip([1,2,3],[7,8,9]).generate()
gen.next()
```

why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `next()` mutates the object that it is called on, so that object must be assigned to a `var` for it to work.  `zip([1,2,3],[7,8,9]).generate()` is immutable until you assign it to a `var`.

Why does `next()` mutate the object?  Because there is an internal index variable that is keeping track of which value to show next.  `next()` uses that internal index and then advances it (mutates it) to point to the next item.